existence of fixed point
I'm trying to prove the following,
$f,g: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ are both continuous functions, and $f \circ g = g \circ f $. Prove that $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ for some $x_0 \in [0,1]$.
I tried contradiction, suppose $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, then $f(f(x))>g(f(x))=f(g(x))>g(g(x))$ holds, but I'm stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This question is similar to: let $f,g:\mathbb{I} \to \mathbb{I} $ continuous functions. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search.
